# How to log Sybase queries in SpringBoot

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, logback, sybase

Is there any way to log all the queries & procedures in Sybase DB with Spring Boot Application having logback ?

As of now, I tried following in my **logback-spring.xml** -

```
<logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" level ="DEBUG">
<appender-ref ref="console"/>
</logger>
```

The above code didn't work for me.
I'm expecting to print/log all the Database queries/Proc in my Logger file/Splunk.

Comment: Add this to `application.properties`: `logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=DEBUG`

Comment: Can we change it to application.yml context ?
Also, application yml looks like this as of now :

**logging:
      config: classpath:logback-spring.xml**